# Check a GET method in URL in all domain laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Hello I created a site by `laravel` and now I need to set a GET method in some times in URL.
but this GET method possible to set all domain.
i want set a ```middle ware`` that covered all site and when set my GET method in URL save the values in table but when don't set my `GET` method don't do anything 
and I don't know how to do this.

middle ware name = `teacherCode`
and get method = `referenceCode`

**my table :**

```sql
table name = referenceCode
columns = id, teacher_code, user_ip, count
```

Comment: Do you want to log the values of all get route ?? Am i right ?

Comment: no just i want to check the url and when url have a get method, save the value in table

Comment: Why you are not putting your middleware on routes that you want to log them?!